# PushNotifications delegate not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I've seen quite a lot of similar questions about it, read and tried multiple solutions proposed but none of them seemed to be working for me.

I can't manage to have the delegates for RemoteNotifications called. Either "DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken" nor "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError".

I'm testing on a device running iOS9 and using XCode7 and Swift. Also on development and only testing on a local device.

Here's my current code, situation and what I tried so far:

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound])
    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    print("Registration successful")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to get token; error: \(error)")
}
```

I already, multiple times, checked and re-generated all the certificates, and provisioning profiles. Making sure that the "Push notifications" were active and that they were linked to the correct AppID and BundleID.

I also checked that I was building and running with the proper Provisioning Profile, both in the Project AND in the target capabilities (in my case the development one)
I checked said provisioning profile if the "aps-environment" was listed (and it is)

When the application launches for the first time, the user is prompted with the choice to accept notifications for the app, but the delegate for the registration is still not called.

I tried to include every information I could, and I tried almost everything so I hope anyone will be able to help me. Even if I missed something stupid :p

Thank you !

[EDIT 1]
After doing some logging with the APS Profile given by Apple on the TechnicalNote 2265 I managed to get more informations:

*2015-09-23 10:42:46 +0200 apsd[102]: : Connected to courier 43-courier.push.apple.com (17.110.225.83)

connection:  onInterface: WWAN

2015-09-23 10:42:46 +0200 apsd[102]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com (null)

2015-09-23 10:42:46 +0200 apsd[102]: : Sending connect message with token '<76c23fe9 639be5c1 dfb5fa3a 5d6af6c9 6f6b9fb2 1e841d01 e3f05b02 1222960a>' onInterface: WWAN with activeInterval 0

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: : Outstanding data received: <08000000 1a010001 00040002 14000800 023c0005 00020003 06000400 000001> (length 31) onInterface: WWAN. Connected on 0 interfaces.

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: : Stream processing: complete yes, invalid no, length parsed 31, parameters {
    APSProtocolCommand = 8;
    APSProtocolConnectedResponse = 0;
    APSProtocolDualChannelSupport = 1;
    APSProtocolLargeMessageSize = 15360;
    APSProtocolMessageSize = 5120;
}

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: : connected response for default user? YES

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]:  asked to change isConnected=NO to YES

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: : Setting dualChannelSupport: YES

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: Server supports dual mode YES  old value YES

2015-09-23 10:42:47 +0200 apsd[102]: : Received connected response OK - connected on 1 interfaces.*

[EDIT 2]
Fixed. I was just missing a 's' in the delegate name. Way to feel silly but at least it works now

Comment: I saw this happen to me once, with a project that had been working for 18 months previously. I don't know what the cause was, I think Xcode or the device  may have got into a funny state. I don't have any useful suggestions other than to uninstall the app, reboot the device, clear Xcode's derived data and clean and relaunch Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try following and see if something works for you:

1. Please ensure that you are not using wild card bundle identifier (ending with *).
2. Please try resetting the device for push enablement for your application. (see below reference)
3. I, personally have experienced this for specific devices. So, please try on a different device and see if you still see the issue.
4. Try different network, preferably open DSL without any firewall and port blockage.

> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or
>   more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back
>   on.

Comment: For the time being I can't get my hand on another device, but I tried the other point you suggested and none of it worked.

Though I did get the APS Log and in the log it's said that I'm successfully connected, that the token is send but nothing happening in my code.
`Connected to courier 8-courier.sandbox.push.apple.com 
Sending connect message with token <....>`

Comment: Interesting, this indicates that the device has successfully established its persistent connection to the push service. Could you please take a look at this Apple' push notification troubleshooting document : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: This link is actually where I read about the log method in the first place. Didn't see much documentation about the log itself but from what they said it's supposed to be working. 
I even found a log entry about a notification I received from another application while debugging.

I guess I will go back to the starting point, maybe the issue is in my code then.

Comment: Well I found the solution : It's "didRegisterForRemoteNotification**s**"
I was apparently missing the 's', silly me for probably not using the auto-completion.
Been struggling for 2 days about a missing 's' haha

Thank you for help still :)
I'll mark your answer as solved since it's quite complete and will probably help someone else

Comment: :)... Glad it worked for you. Sometimes such smaller oversights eats lot of time.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I'm aware, we're unable to natively subscribe to iOS notifications in the simulator. If you need to test this as part of your app though, you can check out something like: https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications

Comment: I know, that's why I said I'm running the app through my device on ios9 at the end.
I'll edit it to make it clearer, thanks for your reply still :)

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?